# Power analysis in structural equation models

Tags: sample-size, structural-equation-modeling, statistical-power

I’m getting different estimates when estimating sample size for a structural equation model when I use different utilities online. How would you calculate the sample size a priori for such a model?

Comment: Could you share more details about the planned analysis and the estimates you have obtained (and their sources)?

Comment: Sure. I plan on doing a latent congruence model (Cheung, 2009).  But, I think even if I'm doing a simple structural model with measurement components I would calculate power the same. Esssentially I have two latent outcomes measured by items (3 items for one and 4 for the other). I will have three latent variables rated by one person (each have 4 items) and the same variables rated by a second person. So six latent variables each with a congruence phantom latent variable. Each congruence variable will predict each outcome. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the online methods? The most appropriate is either a simulation, or the Saris-Satorra method. They should give the same results.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried using utilities I found online at Kris Preacher's website and then Daniel Soper's website. Soper has a calculated for sample size to test structural models whereas it looks like Preacher's website has utilities to calculate sample size to test differences in fit indices. I'm not sure which is the most appropriate to use. I basically have to do the power analysis to show the necessary sample size to find the effects I'm looking for.

Comment: Kris Preacher has a lot of things on his website. What did you use? (I haven't bothered to look at Soper's. Just tell me what you used, what you entered, and what it gave you.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jeremy. I used his tool for computing minimum sample size for RMSEA: http://quantpsy.org/rmsea/rmsea.htm

I have 310 degrees of freedom and used .05 for alpha, .80 for power, .10 for alternative RMSEA, and .04 for null RMSEA.

I'm not even sure if I'm using the right tool, honestly. I'm submitting a front end and proposed methods and analysis to a journal (who will then decide whether to accept or reject - it's the registered reports initiative). They decide before finding out results. I need to give a number for sample size needed for my SE model.